# How to upload file from downloads folder in Android Oreo and above?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to write the code to upload file from Android Oreo and Above. First I am running a intent to get the uri of the file.

```
intent_upload.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
return Intent.createChooser(intent_upload, pickerTitle)
```

But when I select file from downloads folder, it returns a null `filepath` from following code. It works perfectly for devices below Android Oreo but I cannot find any solution for android o and above.

Please help

```
val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id));
return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
```

Code for `getDataColumn` is as follow

```
fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?,
                          selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {

        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)

        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)
            val temp = context
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(index)
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){

        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }
```

It is happening for API 26 and above.

My motive is to upload a pdf file from the downloads folder in Android.

Comment: did you find solution for this ?

Comment: Hi @AYKHO here is the solution. Hope it's not too late.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is past due. I also faced this issue and I was able to find a solution from this gist. [FileUtils.java](https://gist.github.com/HBiSoft/15899990b8cd0723c3a894c1636550a8). Just use this util class in your project

Just leaving this here for people who face this issue in the future. Wasted a couple of hours working on this.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    File originalFile = new File(FileUtils.getRealPath(this,uri));
}
```